# The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class ... Dart console App Error when trying to use Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

I'm trying to write a console Dart App that uses a firestore database as persistence layer, but i'm having this kind of internal library error throwing by firebase when I try to run a basic sample:

```
file:///home/alexandre/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-5.0.2/lib/src/auth.dart:274:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::Auth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
```

my pubspec.yaml is:

```
name: flix_backend_dart
description: A sample command-line application.
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com
# author: alexandre <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.1.0 <3.0.0'

#dependencies:
#  path: ^1.4.1

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.0.0
  firebase: ^5.0.0
```

the snippet from App is:

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:flix_backend_dart/domain/repository.dart';
import 'package:flix_backend_dart/network/load_movies.dart';
import 'package:flix_backend_dart/network/service.dart';




main(List<String> arguments) {
  const _query = 'get:new21';
  const _startYear = 1900;
  const _endYear = 2019;
  const _startNetflixRate = 0.0;
  const _endNetflixRate = 5.0;
  const _startImdbRate = 0.0;
  const _endImdbRate = 10.0;
  const _genreId = 0;
  const _vtype = 'movie';
  const _audio = 'Any';
  const _subtitle = 'Any';
  const _imdbVotes = 100;
  const _downloadable = '';

  final queryParameters = {
    'q':
    '${_query}-!${_startYear},${_endYear}-!${_startNetflixRate},${_endNetflixRate}-!${_startImdbRate},${_endImdbRate}-!${_genreId}-!${_vtype}-!${_audio}-!${_subtitle}-!${_imdbVotes}-!${_downloadable}',
    't': 'ns',
    'cl': '29',
    'st': 'adv',
    'ob': "Relevance",
    'sa': 'and',
    'p': '1'
  };


  var app = initializeApp(
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxirebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxx7012',
      storageBucket: 'storageBucket',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxx18'
  );


  var ref = firestore(app).collection("movies");

  ref.get().then((snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach((doc){
      var imdbid = doc.data()['imdbid'];
      print("imdbid: $imdbid");
    });
  });


  var r =
  GetNewMoviesImpl.instance(FetchMovieServiceImpl(), FirebaseRepository());



  r.execute(queryParameters).then((r) {
    print(r);
  });
}
```

I was able to access this database from a console kotlin app. Am I make anything wrong?

---

Comment: Are you running this code in the browser or outside?

Comment: outside. it's a console App.

Comment: There is no `allowInterop` outside the browser. This function is especially for Dart-js-interop calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `allowInterop` outside the browser. This function is especially for Dart-js-interop calls. The firebase library you're using probably also only can be used in the browser. Only the Firebase admin API is supported on the server/console.

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/firebase_flutter_sdk is a pure Dart approach that should work the same on the server, but I don't know the status.

Comment: thanks. but this is only for flutter? my app doesn't depends on flutter. It's a Dart console App.

Comment: I don't think this is only for Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

If this app only for mobile phones, remove the dependency

firebase: ^5.0.0

This is only for web.

Comment: Worked for me, but why is this?

Comment: Because its only for the web and servers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the `pubspec.lock` file and running the command `flutter pub get` again fixed the problem.

If that doesn't work, try delete the folder `.pub_cache` usually located in the user root:

```
rm ~/.pub_cache
```